# Getting Flask to use the desired URL behind mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a Flask app running under mod_wsgi on Apache. Due to various parts of the website being static and others being dynamic, the dynamic parts of the website are routed to the Flask app using `mod_rewrite` as shown below:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(foo(/.*)?)$    /myapp.wsgi/$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(bar(/.*)?)$    /myapp.wsgi/$1  [L,QSA]
# etc.
```

**myapp.wsgi**

```
from flask import Flask, request

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/foo/")
def foo():
    return request.url

@application.route("/bar/")
def bar():
    return redirect(request.url + "baz/")
```

When I visit `http://www.mywebsite.com/foo/` the page tells me that my URL is `http://www.mywebsite.com/myapp.wsgi/foo/`.

When I visit `http://www.mywebsite.com/bar/` the page redirects me to `http://www.mywebsite.com/myapp.wsgi/bar/baz/`.

This also happens with Flask's automatic redirects: when I visit `http://www.mywebsite.com/foo` (no trailing slash), Flask redirects to add the slash, but it redirects to `http://www.mywebsite.com/myapp.wsgi/foo/`.

Is there an easy way to get the Flask app to not include the `/myapp.wsgi` in the URLs and instead use just use URLs relative to where the routes are? (e.g. `/foo/` and `/bar/`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by removing the name of the script from the `SCRIPT_NAME` environment variable using some middleware as in the below example taken from the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/fastcgi/#configuring-apache).

```
from yourapplication import app

class ScriptNameStripper(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ''
    return self.app(environ, start_response)

app = ScriptNameStripper(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well but you might want to use `url_for` function documented here :
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for

It allows you to construct URLs by referencing endpoints of you application.
For example `url_for('bar')` would construct the relative URL pointing the bar endpoint.

Comment: That is an option, although that wouldn't help when flask provides redirects byitself. e.g. when the URL is missing a trailing slash, Flask automatically redirects to the URL with the trailing slash. I've updated the question with this.

Comment: You can remove the redirect on slashes behavior by using the `strict_slashes` parameters in `route` but I admit it doesn't really answer the issue. Have you tried setting the application_root in you configuration? `application.config.udpate(APPLICATION_ROOT="myapp.wsgi")`

Comment: I've tried setting `APPLICATION_ROOT` to `myapp.wsgi` but that just seems to ensure the current behaviour. I've also tried setting it to `/` and `www.mywebsite.com`, as well as setting `SERVER_NAME` to `www.mywebsite.com` but none has worked.